# Solution to second order homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a,b,c$ be positive numbers. How do I show that all solutions of $ay''(t)+by'(t)+cy(t)=0$ approach zero as $t$ approach infinity?

Comment: find answer then calculate limit.

Comment: @RaziehNoori But how do I find answer? Are there not a lot of different answers possible?

Comment: @Barry_Allen Perhaps you can include some details of your attempts so far? What do you know about finding the solutions to homogeneous, linear ODEs like this one?

Comment: see for example $aλ^2+b\lambda+c=0$  if it has two real distinct root both have to be negative, if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ similarly.. –

Comment: If you would know the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$, how would you solve this differential equation?